# Angular: Combine two mat-error elements to one

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I'm pretty new to Angular and I followed the tutorial on their official site. Out of interest I played around and I want to ask if there is a possibility to combine the error handling (done with Angular Material) when an user inputs hers/his mail. Depending on what error code happens, I display a different error message.

```js
errorHandling = (control: string, error: string) => {
  return this.checkoutForm.controls[control].hasError(error);
}
```

```html
<div>
 <mat-form-field>
  <input matInput placeholder="Enter your email" formControlName="email">
   <!-- How to combine these two mat-error elements to one? -->
   <mat-error *ngIf="errorHandling('email', 'required')">
    Enter email
   </mat-error>
   <mat-error *ngIf="errorHandling('email', 'email')">
    Invalid email
   </mat-error>
 </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you can make a function. this function can get the first error of all the errors

```
  getError(control:AbstractControl)
  {
        let error=null;
        if (control.errors)
        {
          const firstKey = Object.keys(control.errors)[0];
          switch (firstKey)
          {
              case 'required':
                 error={error:'required'}
                 break;
              case 'minlength':
                 error={error:' is required '+control.errors.minlength.requiredLength+' characteres'}
                 break;
              case 'pattern':
                 error={error:' don\'t match with pattern'}
                 break;
              case 'maxlength':
                 error={error:' is required less than '+control.errors.maxlength.requiredLength+' characteres'}
                 break;
          }
        }
        return error
    }
```

Then

```
   <mat-error >
     getError(form.get('email')?.error)
   </mat-error>
```

Or iterate over all the errors

```
  getError2(control:AbstractControl)
  {
        let error=[];
        if (control.errors)
        {
          Object.keys(control.errors).forEach(firstKey=>{
          switch (firstKey)
          {
              case 'required':
                 error.push({error:'required'})
                 break;
              case 'minlength':
                 error.push({error:' is required '+control.errors.minlength.requiredLength+' characteres'})
                 break;
              case 'pattern':
                 error.push({error:' don\'t match with pattern'})
                 break;
              case 'maxlength':
                 error.push({error:' is required less than '+control.errors.maxlength.requiredLength+' characteres'})
                 break;
          }
          })
        }
        return error.length?error.map(x=>x.error).join(','):null
        //we can return the array too
        // return error.length?error:null
    }
```

And write

```
<mat-error >
   {{getError2(userAddressValidations.get('firstName'))}}
</mat-error>

//if we received  an array
<mat-error >
  <ul>
  <li *ngFor="let error of getError2(userAddressValidations.get('firstName'))">
  {{error.error}}
  </li>
  </ul>
</mat-error>
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-form-validation-eg-gk3ltl?file=app/input-error-state-matcher-example.ts)

Answer (score 0):

You can just check if the `errors` object exists on the form control. If there are any errors, then it will be a valid object with each key referring to the error. If there are no errors, then it will be a `null` value.

```
<div>
 <mat-form-field>
  <input matInput placeholder="Enter your email" formControlName="email">
   <!-- Just check if the errors object exists on the form control -->
   <mat-error *ngIf="checkoutForm.controls['email'].errors">
    Combined error message
   </mat-error>
 </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, I got it - and regarding the error message. After using your suggestion it's always showing me the same error message (either the input field is empty or email is not valid).

Comment: the snippet shows a combined error message for any error that happens on the field. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: Not exactly - as I wrote initially: 'Depending on what error code happens, I display a different error message.'