# Show multiple form errors in angualr

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to show multiple errors under the angular 15 form field. However, this is not manageable because errors overflow into controls at the bottom. My idea is to show one error message and show an ellipsis and badge(indicate the number of errors). And when users hover over the ellipsis you will see the rest of the errors.

See the code below. I was able to achieve this using the logic below, however, this is not scalable and template logic gets super complicated. In addition, error messages have to be duplicated in multiple places. Is there a better approach to solve this issue maybe using another component or different error handling logic?

```
<div class="form-field-container">
          <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
          <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <input matInput [readonly]="isEditMode" minlength="8" placeholder="Password"
              [type]="!hide ? 'password' : 'text'"
              pattern="^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*#?&]{8,}$" formControlName="password"
              required>
            <button mat-icon-button matSuffix (click)="hide = !hide" *ngIf="!isEditMode" color="primary" type='button'>
              <svg-icon [src]="hide ? 'visibility_off' :'visibility'"></svg-icon>
            </button>
            <mat-error
              *ngIf="!((password && password.errors?.minlength) && (password && password.errors?.pattern || password.errors?.weakPassword))">
              <span *ngIf="password && password.errors?.minlength">
                Password must be at least 8 characters long.
              </span>
              <span *ngIf="password && password.errors?.pattern || password.errors?.weakPassword">
                Password requires uppercase, lowercase letters and numbers.
              </span>
            </mat-error>
            <mat-error
              *ngIf="((password && password.errors?.minlength) && (password && password.errors?.pattern || password.errors?.weakPassword))">
                Password must be at least 8 characters long<span matBadge="1" matBadgeColor="accent" matTooltip="Password requires uppercase, lowercase letters and numbers.">
                  ...
                </span>
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
```

Comment: If you want to show several errors, you can change the height of the mat-form-field  and show all the errors. Take a look to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60088911/angular-combine-two-mat-error-elements-to-one/60090702#60090702) -give the value to the input, e.g. "a2" to see in action.

Answer (score 0):

What about looping through `form.errors` using *ngFor, and displaying `error.message` in your template?

Comment: but I only want to show just one at all times and then if there are multiple I want to show a badge with the rest of the error count and show those errors on hover on the badge